How to force Chrome PDFs to use BGR or grayscale anti-aliasing in Windows 11:?
My monitor has BGR subpixel layout. File Explorer and webpages properly antialias for BGR subpixels:

However, Chrome PDFs antialias for RGB:

which – on a BGR monitor – looks worse than grayscale anti-aliasing.
Apparently Windows is aware of my subpixel layout because of the way that I answered the ClearType calibration questions. Unfortunately, despite Windows having ClearType since Windows 7, Chrome's PDF rendering does not respect the calibration values provided by the OS. What a shame.
Is there a way to set Chrome PDF rendering to either BGR or grayscale?
Update: The always-RGB antialiasing appears to be a Chrome issue, as Edge on the same PC anti-aliases the same PDF file in grayscale:

For now, therefore, I have set Edge as my default application for .pdf files. On some PCs, grayscale AA is enabled by going to edge://flags and setting New PDF Viewer to Enabled. Thank you user K J for figuring this out.
Update: After viewing a few PDFs in grayscale AA, I realized that I miss the subpixel anti-aliasing. It is in fact clearer than grayscale anti-aliasing. So while Edge is better than Chrome for BGR monitors, neither is ideal unless there is a way to select the subpixel layout.

Hmm I earlier also suggested Firefox as a different method of rendering (pixel images of text) so it does its own antialiasing and unsure if you can flip PDF RGB to different but in chrome there may well be setting that would need to  be queried at Chromium forum/bug reports
